# DBACOCKPIT tcode on two SAP systems look different, why?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I have 2 different systems with SAP installed on them. First installation running on SQLServer, and the other installation running on Oracle.

In the first installation of SAP running on SqlServer, when i run DBACOCKPIT tcode, i get the following subfolders;

Performance, Space, Backup And Recovery, Configuration, Jobs, Alerts, Diagnostics, Download.

However, on the second installation of SAP running on Oracle. I get the following sub folders only: **Performance, Space, Jobs, Diagnostics**.
Why don't i get the other folders?

Both systems run ECC 6.0

[image: SAP installed on SqlServer, DBACOCKPIT with full list]

[image: SAP installed on Oracle, DBACOCKPIT with partial list]

SAP Basis components of both are a bit different:

[image: SAP on SqlServer, SAP_BASIS component is 702]
[image: SAP on Oracle, SAP_BASIS component is 700]

Comment: Is the `SAP_BASIS` component the same in both systems? Could you post the component information window of both systems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is absolutely standard situation.
I am also have a two systems with the same version of ECC.
One on MS SQL Server 2014
Another one on SAP HANA SPS03 
and
DBACOCKPIT t-code looks different in these two systems.
All OK!

Answer (score 1):

Despite the difference of DBACOCKPIT layouts between MS SQL system (A) and Oracle system (B), I think it is normal. Possible reasons for this are:

- lack of necessary user authorizations on system B
- different set of authorizations of user A and user B
- Oracle database was configured incorrectly or was not configured at all

SAP Note [1028624](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1028624) regarding Oracle DBACOCKPIT says

> - Some performance monitors within the DBA Cockpit require special database objects. These objects are created using an SQL script. See Note 706927 for this script and more information.
> - Some functions in the DBA Cockpit require the Oracle Active Workload Repository. This Oracle option must therefore be available for selection (see Note 1028068).

This note also exactly specifies set of functions available in DBACOCKPIT for Oracle, and this set fully corresponds to your screenshot.

> The DBA Cockpit has a navigation area that is visible in all the functions of the DBA Cockpit. This area contains a menu tree with the following access points:
>   - Performance (corresponds to the old transaction ST04)
>   - Space       (corresponds to the old transaction DB02)
>   - Jobs        (corresponds to the old transactions DB13, DB12, DB14, DB13C)
>   - Diagnostics

At the same time MS SQL DBACOCKPIT also corresponds to SAP standard, which is confirmed by SAP Note [1027512](http://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1027512) and by [this datasheet](http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/go/portal/prtroot/docs/library/uuid/1062428c-f1df-2910-b08f-c322feddcd10?QuickLink=index&overridelayout=true&13542031901813), for example.

Possible steps for research:

1. check if authorizations S_RZL_ADMIN and S_BTCH_ALL are assigned to you, as it stated in detailed DBACOCKPIT description from note [1028624](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1028624).
2. check [SAP Database Oracle Guide](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw73/helpdata/en/47/1cc1ee41f64406e10000000a1553f6/content.htm?frameset=/en/47/0e59d19c540e8ae10000000a155369/frameset.htm&current_toc=/en/0b/5daf09b03344ad97338f838e09b9ee/plain.htm&node_id=24) for compliance with you system B setup

Answer (score 0):

Dbacockpit view depends on type of database.